# How to get the code for sharing the image of a facebook application to the users timeline?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can I get the correct code of **Facebook application**, which allows to share or post the result image of the application to the users wall(**Timeline**).

Presently I am using the code below;-

```
 $attachment = array(
   'message' => 'this is my message',
   'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!  https://apps.facebook.com/whoisyourmillionare/',
   'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
   'description' => 'this is a description',
   'picture' => 'http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg');
   $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
```

and the out put is as per in the **image 1**

Actually I need to be as **image 2**

[image]

Comment: Try posting to /me/photos instead of /me/feed
You should change picture to image

Comment: I got a error like this "OAuthException(#324) Requires upload file"
My intension is not to upload, to share in the wall of user.

Comment: Take a look at this example:
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/)

Comment: Yes..its cleared. Thanks for your answer.